# Is there a way/extension to exclude certain line(s) from "Format On Save" in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, autoformatting

I am working on a Python project where the Formatting is set to Autopep8. Is there any extension or possible settings where can define to exclude a certain line(s) from formatting when VS is set to format modified code/file on save or with keyboard shortcuts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add the comment `# noqa` to the end of each line you want VS Code to leave alone. For instance, to prevent VS Code from changing

```py
RED     = 0
YELLOW  = 1
```

to

```py
RED = 0
YELLOW = 1
```

just do the following:

```py
RED     = 0  # noqa
YELLOW  = 1  # noqa
```

Answer (score 7):

You can take:

```
# autopep8: off
# autopep8: on
```

or

```
# fmt: off
# fmt: on
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, Steven. Your suggestion works also but since Thomas' answer was earlier, in one line, and also his profile has a lower rating, I decided to approve his answer. Of course, your solution is better for multi-line exceptions.

Comment: @Zarik Thanks for your response, have a good day : ) you are a nice guy.

Comment: It's working pretty fine for *autopep8* vscode extension!

Answer (score 2):

### Multiple lines:

For **black** and **autopep8**:

```
# fmt: off
RED     = 0
YELLOW  = 1
# fmt: on
```

For **black** and **yapf**:

```
# yapf: disable
RED     = 0
YELLOW  = 1
# yapf: enable
```

For **autopep8**:

```
# autopep8: off
RED     = 0
YELLOW  = 1
# autopep8: on
```

### One line:

For **black**:

```
BLUE    = 0  # fmt: skip
```

For **yapf**:

```
BLUE    = 0  # yapf: disable
```