# [Dart][Flutter] How to exclude multi-lines from "Format On Save" in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

I am working on a Flutter project where the Formatting is set to the default Dart recommends VSCode formatter setting. Is there any way to exclude multi-lines from formatting when VS is set to format modified code/file on save?

I refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70074250/8181863) to exclude each line. The code below worked:

```
      msg.pose.covariance = [
        0.25, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, // noqa
        0.0, 0.25, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, // noqa
        0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, // noqa
        0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, // noqa
        0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, // noqa
        0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 2.25 // noqa
      ];
```

Now I want to exclude multi-lines with similar this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73436253/8181863). The expected code like Python (**black** formatter):

```
      // dart: fmt_off
      msg.pose.covariance = [
        0.25, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
        0.0, 0.25, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
        0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
        0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
        0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
        0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 2.25
      ];
      // dart: fmt_on
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[As explained in the Dart formatter's FAQ](https://github.com/dart-lang/dart_style/wiki/FAQ#why-does-the-formatter-mess-up-my-collection-literals), you just need to have a single comment within the collection literal to prevent the formatter from reformatting it:

> So, if you have a collection that you have carefully split into lines, add at least one line comment somewhere inside it to get it to preserve all of the newlines in it.

Comment: Should I separate each row to a new variable, and use like `data = [...row1,..row2,]` for better readability? My case using [Matrix4](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/vector_math_64/Matrix4-class.html) showing 4x4 grid.

Comment: @YeasinSheikh I probably wouldn't consider that to be more readable for a 2D matrix, but really it's up to you.